# How to load content for external URL in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I am trying to build RSS reader where there are a bunch of URLs and clicking on one of them loads the content for the selected content.

My attempt looks like

```
import React from "react";
import Listings from "./listings"
import Content from "./content"

const urls = [
  "https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-switch/wp/2017/10/17/googles-pixel-2-gives-you-the-best-of-android-if-you-can-find-it/?utm_term=.dacb8f419a4b",
  "https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2017/10/windows-10-fall-creators-update-lots-of-small-changes-and-maybe-the-revolution/",
  "https://www.theverge.com/2017/10/17/16481628/microsoft-surface-book-2-price-release-date-specs-availability-processor"
];

export default class RSS extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      selectedUrl: urls[0],
      urls: urls,
      content: "TBD"
    }
  }

  onUrlSelect = (e, url) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //console.log("selected Url Index: ", url);
    this.setState({selectedUrl: url});

  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.loadData(this.state.selectedUrl);
  }

  loadData = (url) => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(url + " -> " + response.ok);
        return response.body;
      })
      .then(function (data) {
        console.log("data: ", data);
        this.setState({ content: data });
      }.bind(this))
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log("failed to load ", url, err.stack);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Listings urls={this.state.urls} onUrlSelect={this.onUrlSelect}/>
        <Content data={this.state.data}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Where `Content` looks like

```
import React from "react";

export default function Content(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p> Loading: {props.data} </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I try to load it, Nothing prints out. However, on the `Developer Tools > Console`, I see

```
data:  ReadableStream {}locked: (...)__proto__: Object
index.js? [sm]:35
```

My code is available on https://codesandbox.io/s/wkwm8z3xl

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

**update**
I changed my code to read `response.text()` and then on the `view` I did the following

```
export default function Content(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: props.data}}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

as recommended in https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

However, the page the results as output is not exactly how it should be
[image]

The code is updated at https://codesandbox.io/s/wkwm8z3xl
This is happening because the other assets like `css`, `images` are not fetched.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `Response.body` is a `ReadableStream`, see [Streams standard](https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/)

Comment: I updated my answer, thanks

Comment: Why do you not use `.text()`?

Comment: I am using `response.text()`, is that not what you are asking for as well?

Comment: What is the issue with result?

Comment: See the image I posted above, it is garbled and no images or styling is available

Comment: Where are images and styles loaded at `document`?

Comment: They are not and I do not know how to load them

Comment: You can use `<link>` element to load CSS. Not certain why images are expected to be present in `document` if not appended to HTML `document`?

Comment: well, if you see the first URL https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-switch/wp/2017/10/17/googles-pixel-2-gives-you-the-best-of-android-if-you-can-find-it/?utm_term=.79a312dd515b , the images are present

Comment: Have you read the response? The response include scripts which use relative paths.

Comment: @daydreamer, I'm curious if you found a workaround for loading the static assets

Comment: @Rowland, I didn't unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

> return response.body

This line doesn't actually give you the data in the body. To get access to the data in the body, you'll need to use one of a couple functions. It looks like the data you're getting back is just a text file, so you'll want to do `return response.text()`. You can read more about extracting the body from Fetch here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Body

One other thing you'll need to fix is that when you call setState, you're setting the data onto `state.content`, but then in your render function you're expecting it to be on `this.state.data`. One or the other will need to change.

Comment: I updated my answer, `response.text()` helps, but does not loads the external assets

Answer (score 0):

> You should use response.text() method to reads content.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response

```
loadData = (url) => {
  fetch(url)
    .then(function (response) {
      // console.log(url + " -> " + response.ok);
      if(response.ok){
        return response.text();
      }
      throw new Error('Error message.');
    })
    .then(function (data) {
      console.log("data: ", data);
      this.setState({ content: data });
    }.bind(this))
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log("failed to load ", url, err.message);
    });
}
```